# What does "off-state output terminal voltage" in optocouplers mean?

Tags: opto-isolator, optoelectronics

I was looking at possible options of what optocouplers to use in my project. I was looking at these parts.

https://www.fairchildsemi.com/search/?searchText=MOC3023-M#N=&&Nao=0&&Ntk=All&&Ntt=MOC3023-M&&Ntx=mode+matchallpartial&&Nty=1&&showAll=true&&showHrd=false

I am looking for a zero-crossing optocoupler.

As I look into their data sheet, I came into the term *"off-state output terminal voltage"* I tried googling the term but it just redirects me to data sheets of other components. It just so happens that also this *"off-state output terminal voltage"* is the only major difference in the datasheets of the optocouplers that I see.

Can I get the MOC3163M that is rated off-state output terminal voltage = 600v even though my application is using 220 V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the maximum voltage you can have across the detector pin when it's turned off.

It is equivalent to the Vce max of a BJT or Vds max of a MOS.

Any value below it will work fine.